# Rails : Validates_format_of for float not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, floating-point, format

I am new at Ruby on Rails.
I was trying to validate format of one of the attribute to enter only float.

```
validates :price, :format => { :with => /^[0-9]{1,5}((\.[0-9]{1,5})?)$/, :message => "should be float" }
```

but when I enter only character in price, it accepts it and show 0.0 value for price.
can anybody tell, what is wrong in this or why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A float is a number and regular expressions are for strings.

It appears that when you enter a string for the float, it gets converted as 0.0 automatically by Rails.

Do you have a default (0.0) on the column? If yes, then you may try removing it and use `validates_presence_of :price` only.

---

Something to try: instead of putting the string directly into the `price` column, put it into a `price_string` attr and use a `before_save` callback to try to convert the string to price. Something like that:

```
attr_accessor :price_string

before_save :convert_price_string

protected
  def convert_price_string
    if price_string
      begin
        self.price = Kernel.Float(price_string)
      rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
        errors.add(ActiveRecord::Errors.default_error_messages[:not_a_number])
      end
    end
```

And in your form, change the name of the text_field to `:price_string`.

Comment: @goodEnogh - thnx for replying but i have not set anything default for price and i have validated presence of price. But, it is same.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar - ok, Rails must still be converting the text to 0.0 for some reason. The Rails controllers do some automatic conversions so maybe you could try validating the input string before creating/updating the object.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar - I've added something to try, I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, but it might work.

Comment: @GoodEnough-thnx for replying, but i think this is a big debug, but i have got the solution for it

    validates_numericality_of :price

by placing this validation it is possible to check for float value.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar : I may be wrong, but I believe that `validates_numericality_of` on a float field will always be true.

Answer (score 18):

This is my solution,

`validates :price,presence:true, numericality: {only_float: true}`

when you fill in for example 7 it automatically transfer the value to 7.0

Answer (score 3):

For rails 3:

```
validates :price, :format => { :with => /^\d+??(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/ }, 
:numericality =>{:greater_than => 0}
```